# docker RDS aws access

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, docker, connection, rds

In Docker I get the following error when I run the docker images:

> "com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException:
>   Communications link failure".

Is there any limitations to access RDS via Docker container? Do we need to enable any settings in RDS to communicate with Docker?

Comment: Can you provide more details about what settings you're using?  Can you connect to the same RDS server from the same EC2 instance without Docker?  (My immediate intuition here is "something about security groups"; Docker shouldn't make a difference.)

Comment: are you able to connect your app to your RDS without docker?

Comment: Yes i'm able to connect ame RDS server from the same EC2 instance without Docker.

Comment: While connecting via Docker i'm unable to connect Databases. And also within the ec2 instances i can access the domain . While trying to connect host domain via browsers im unable to access.